# Can a Lambda Function expose an IP Address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

For my application on AWS, I want to host a temporary HTTP server and dispose it in a few minutes. I think EC2 instance / Fargate would be a costly overkill for this. So thinking of doing this on a Lambda function. Is this possible?

Can a Lambda function expose an IP address (could be temporary)? Or provide some way for others to communicate with the lambda function - after it has started?

Or is there any other way to achieve this goal?

**Adding more detail**:
I want to achieve something like this. The external client invokes an API, to get a URL. The client should then be able to interact with this URL in a stateful session, defined by the parameters passed in the initial API invocation.

This session would last a couple of minutes, after which the state/session/client is forgotten. The Lambda will use the time between requests to work in the background and prepare for next request from the client.

I know we can do this by saving session details in the dynamodb, triggering a fresh lambda function for every new request from the client, and more lambda functions in the background with SNS... But, I thought would be more exciting to do everything in a single Lambda invocation

Comment: Could you please describe your larger use-case? That is, what end result are you trying to achieve that would use this 'temporary server'? We might be able to provide an alternative method.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for looking into this. I have updated the question with more details about the usecase.

Comment: I still don't understand your actual use-case. That is, _why_ do you wish to create "temporary HTTP servers"? What is the business goal that all this is achieving?

Comment: It is used in a web application, to allow end user to fill in details via a chain of forms. The next form is defined by the information provided in the previous form. The algorithm for defining the next form is quite complex and secure, so want to do it on the server rather than doing it in an Angular app running in the browser. So I want to have the individual client to interact with a particular lambda instance and finish the job without involving the rest of the stack.

Answer (score 3):

To allow others interact with your Lambda function you would need to set it up with either one of the following:

- API Gateway - This option would be more preferable for an API, take a look at the documentation for [Build an API Gateway REST API with Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html).
- Application Load Balancer - This option would be more preferable for a traditional HTTP application. Take a look at the blog post on [Lambda functions as targets for Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/lambda-functions-as-targets-for-application-load-balancers/).

An application load balancer will take a few minutes to setup, and require a base VPC configured if you intend to use this.

You will also need to consider DNS for any of these options, both will give endpoints but these will be AWS domain names. If you want to give them a hostname on your domain you would need to ensure to keep low TTLs on any wildcard subdomain records (i.e. `*.example.com`).

Comment: These are ways of triggering a Lambda function. I want others to communicate with the Lambda function after it has started. The lambda function would host a simple HTTP server, and others would make HTTP calls to this server running on the Lambda function.

Comment: If you want others to invoke your Lambda without giving them programmatic access (IAM user with SDK/CLI) then these are the ways in which you would expose it :)